# How to verify keyboard shown on android/ios device screen using appium

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-ios

Need to verify keyboard is shown on device screen(android/ios).

Not able to identify keyboard element on screen. So tried using the below method. But its not working.

`isKeyboardShown()`  - it is showing as undefined for the type of appium driver.

using appium version - 7.4.1

```
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.1</version>
```

Is there any other appium method or way to check this?

Answer (score 0):

`isKeyboardShown` is the right way to check it and works on both Android and iOS platform.

In order to use it, you need to properly create an instance of driver (AndroidDriver/iOSDriver):

```
        driver = new AndroidDriver(appiumURL, capabilities);

        boolean isDisplayed = driver.isKeyboardShown();
```

Answer (score 0):

`isKeyboardShown()` is the correct way to do it, you just need to cast your driver, in case you are using an AppiumDriver to AndroidDriver or IOSDriver depending on the case, like:
`((AndroidDriver)driver).isKeyboardShown();`
`((IOSDriver)driver).isKeyboardShown();`

Answer (score -2):

Try declaring the keyboard container as an element and verify it with isDisplayed()

Comment: Keyboard container element is not identified. Can't use isDisplayed() as locator is not identifiable.